# Chunk Text Files in R

Tags: r

I am trying to modify in the R environment a set of approximately 300 plays that I have as .txt files. Ideally, I'd like to chunk all of them into segments of about 500 words. I am unsure of the process for this, however.

I began with this attempt:

```
chunk.size <- 500
texts <- list.files(pattern="*.txt")
texts <- paste(readLines(texts), collapse=" ")
texts.lower <- tolower(texts)
texts.lower <- strsplit(words.lower, "\\s+")
texts <- unlist(words.lower)
x <- seq_along(texts)
text.chunks <- split(texts, ceiling(x/chunk.size))
```

I get, however, an error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
```

Comment: `readLines` likes one file at a time, not a vector of multiple filenames as you're providing in `texts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little to go on here. I'll assume you can easily generate a list of files (`lof`), and you are not concerned with breaking the string on white-space boundaries.

This returns a list where each element (referenced by the filename) contains an entire file. This element will be a vector of strings, each exactly `blockSize` characters or less (for the last chunk).

```
blockSize <- 500
lof <- list.files(pattern='*.txt')
listOfTextBlocks <- sapply(lof, function(f) {
    txt <- paste(readLines(f), collapse='\n')
    nch <- nchar(txt)
    ind <- seq(1, nch, by=blockSize)
    substring(txt, ind, c(ind[-1]-1, nch))
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

If this doesn't match your needs, please provide [better guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

***EDIT***

This will break at white-space boundaries.

```
blockSize <- 500
lof <- list.files(pattern='*.md')
listOfTextBlocks <- sapply(lof, function(f) {
    txt <- scan(f, character(0))
    n <- 1:length(txt)
    split(txt, ceiling(n/blockSize))
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

This gives you a list-of-lists.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I edited my post with my initial (albeit poor) attempt. Your answer provides much more than I was able to get (though somehow simpler). This returns chunks of 500 characters, however, rather than words. Is this what nchar is doing?

Comment: No, `nchar` just counts characters in a string; it is analogous to `length` of a list/vector. See [`?nchar`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/nchar.html).